# How to check if any checkbox is selected or not in android with kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
    submit_btn.setOnClickListener {
                var result = ""
                if(rb_gender.checkedRadioButtonId != -1)
                    {
                        result += " Gender: "
                    }
                    if(rb_male.isChecked) result += " Male \n"
                    if(rb_female.isChecked)  result += "Female \n"

       result += " Language Known:  "

            if(cb_english.isChecked) result+= " English"
            if(cb_hindi.isChecked) result+= " Hindi "
            if(cb_punjabi.isChecked) result+= " Punjabi"

               else   result = " PLEASE SELECT GENDER AND LANGUAGE \n"

            result_textView.text = result
        }
    }
}
```

//This code is not working on some condition like if I select Male and English then complier run else part......but that's not true

Comment: What's the problem with this code?

Comment: Complier direct print Please select language if 2 checkbox are selected ....if I select all checkbox then it will be stored in variable result else not

Comment: Do you want to add three lang when all three are selected?

Comment: I want to run else part when user not select any checkbox......and if user select any one or two checkbox it will be stored in variable result

Comment: If you could attach the resultant UI and what you are currently facing then it would be easier to help with @GurarshdeepSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    var flag = 0

        if(cb_english.isChecked) {
                result+= " English"
                flag = 1
        }
        if(cb_hindi.isChecked) {
                result+= " Hindi "
                flag = 1
        }
        if(cb_punjabi.isChecked) {
                result+= " Punjabi"
                flag = 1
        }
        if(flag == 0){   
                result = " PLEASE SELECT LANGUAGE \n"
        }
```

Comment: PLEASE SELECT LANGUAGE also execute with selected Checkboxes

Answer (score -1):

you can use  string and check if its value is empty or null that means user did not select any checkbox and if its have value that mean user select a check box simple.

Comment: He wants to select multiple options so can't use radio button

Comment: Radio button are not useful in case of language known as someone may know more than one languages